# How to print a large number of URLs to PDF

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, url, print-to-pdf

I have a long list of URLs which I wish to store locally as PDF printouts. Accessing the URLs requires me to log into a website, so I need to do the initial login with a browser. Once I'm logged into the site, I can load any URL and print it to PDF.

Currently, I'm browsing to each URL one at a time and printing them to PDF manually using Chrome's "Save as PDF" print option.

How can I go straight from the list of URLs to the finished PDF documents without needing to manually browse to and print each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found non in Chrome, but there's one Firefox add-ons doing just that. It works for me on Mac.

```
Universal Print
by Y Harrow
```

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/universal-print/

Comment: When paired with an "open list of links" extension and PDF printer driver, this meets the requirement. I don't suppose you know of a PDF printer driver which will use the URL as the name instead of prompting?

Comment: That's way too geeky for a printer driver!